# PhpStorm: how to enable inspections highlight

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

Could you help me, I have lost highlighting level on my PhpStorm, and don't know, where I can it enable again.

How look my Hektor settings now:

[image]

How it was, before "something" happens:

[image]

Comment: Need to see more details. 1) Is that a PHP file (does file has PHP icon)? 2) What did you do before it happens? I mean -- some new plugins installed etc? 3) Does it work in other files? 4) Maybe you have disabled all PHP inspections? etc. 5) Share your `idea.log` perhaps ... Right now I have little to no clues where to start.

Comment: Thanks. I solved that problem by "dirty" method. I've deleted my .idea settings folder in my project, and everything worked as it should. Maybe it will be helpful for someone with that problem like mine.